# Linq: group by doesn't work

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem with getting my GROUP BY to work correctly. Can some see why?

```
public void MonthlyTurnover(int year, int month) {
            var q1 = (from sp in _db.Species
                from p in _db.Pets
                from b in _db.Bookings.Where(x => x.ExpectedArrivalTime.Year == year &&
                    x.ExpectedArrivalTime.Month == month)
                where p.SpeciesId == sp.Id && b.PetId == p.Id && b.PetId == p.Id
                select new {sp.SpeicesName, Sum = b.Services.Sum(i => i.Price)}).ToList();

            foreach (var v in q1) {
                Console.WriteLine(v);
            }
}
```

What I get without group by

[image]

```
public void MonthlyTurnover(int year, int month) {
            var q1 = (from sp in _db.Species
                from p in _db.Pets
                from b in _db.Bookings.Where(x => x.ExpectedArrivalTime.Year == year &&
                    x.ExpectedArrivalTime.Month == month)
                where p.SpeciesId == sp.Id && b.PetId == p.Id && b.PetId == p.Id
                select new {sp.SpeicesName, Sum = b.Services.Sum(i => i.Price)})
                .GroupBy(x => new{x.SpeicesName, x.Sum}).ToList();

            foreach (var v in q1) {
                Console.WriteLine(v.Key);
            }
}
```

What I get with group by

[image]

and what I want…

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group just by `SpeicesName`, try this:

```
var q1 = (from sp in _db.Species
                from p in _db.Pets
                from b in _db.Bookings.Where(x => x.ExpectedArrivalTime.Year == year &&
                    x.ExpectedArrivalTime.Month == month)
                where p.SpeciesId == sp.Id && b.PetId == p.Id && b.PetId == p.Id
                select new {sp.SpeicesName, Sum = b.Services.Sum(i => i.Price)})
                .GroupBy(x => x.SpeicesName).Select(g=>new {SpeicesName=g.Key,Sum=g.Sum(e=>e.Sum)}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't group by the Sum... just group by the Species Name.

```
...
.GroupBy(x => x.SpeicesName).ToList();
```

Now you've got a series of groups where the key is the species name. You can display the species name (once), and then sum all the individual sums.

```
foreach (var v in q1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", v.Key, v.Sum(x => x.Sum)); // "Dog: 7500", "Cat: 3500", etc
}
```